# General Engineering - Organizing Information, Ideas, Projects, Reference Material, Physical Parts etc

Tags: design

As you work on project and learn new things there is information and things learned that you want to refer to in the future.  The commonly used things are not a problem, when used enough you usually remember.  But there ends up being thousands of pieces of app notes/ personal notes / how-to's etc that are occasionally useful.

Then there is all the locations, where the project source code repository is, the library files for 3D / Schematic / PCB and all the other assets.

Then there is all the tools such as compilers, IDE's and the required versions of each that were used to create the project files.

Then there is all of the To-do's, project tasks, stuff that needs to get ordered, stuff that maybe could be ordered for experimentation/research in the future.

Then there are all the books that should be read at some point in time.

Once you end up with enough of these "things" to track you can end up spending most of your time just curating the collection of these things, if you want to attempt to keep things organized.

Is there any ideas from anyone as to how you manage the overwhelming amount of information, projects, ideas and things and the relationships between them all?  I hate having to re-learn stuff if it is not documented enough but I also hate searching for things I stored previously if it is not organized well enough.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: Actually it has everything to do with electronic design, granted not the wire this to that but how do you deal with the management of information and resources

Comment: I stopped reading about 1/2 through...

Comment: Shortened, was long.  Basically I am asking how do you manage the information and assets (code/knowledge/physical things) that make up a project

Comment: It really has nothing to do about electronic design. It boils down to, how do I stay organized? Regardless, every single engineer and company will have their own procedures for this.

Comment: You might find the Personal Productivity stack exchange more fruitful than here. There are a variety of time management (the old term) techniques, plus the formal project management techniques and software (MS Project, Gantt charts, and all the methods recommended by the [PMI](http://www.pmi.org/)).

Comment: Although the orchestrating of an electronics project can be run like any other project, nothing beats a system that is developed with electronics in mind. Even though this question is not about volts and sparks, I do believe it has merit and should at least be treated as such.

Comment: Web based resources can be very usefully referenced via indexing services like Pinterest  - [This is my "TECH" page - enjoy :-}](http://www.pinterest.com/russellmcmahon/tech/) | You can have many folders and you can hide them if desired - I have some hidden ones for specific non-public tasks. | [My top levfel page here  - 29 "boards" it says](http://www.pinterest.com/russellmcmahon/)

Comment: There are many packages aimed at data referencing. Or you can use EXCEL or a database program to create your own.

Comment: An immensely useful and powerful and just slightly risky system is to use an online email service like GMail to receive copies of all documents. You can index these with their labelling system but can also add text in subject lines or body that can then be searched for. I prepend an underbar to words that I want to be especially findable to separate them from normal text. So eg a line may read _lifepo4 _charging. I can then easily recover all emails with those words in them. You can focus on words in the subject line or not specify.

Comment: You need to learn how eg GMail handles searches as it tends to logical OR search terms if not careful.   I have ?30GB?+ in GMail - going back to late 2007 when I joined. Invaluable, and accessible worldwide (harder in China alas). BUT do not depend on it. Even Google may decide to do something silly with your data one day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some mind mapping software like **[FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Screenshots)**. It could help you to organize your collected information, ideas and references.